# get text value from database without linebreak to use it javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have some text in my database and I want get it to store in javascript variable but because of data has linebreak thay doesn't store in variable
can you help me?(sorry for my bad english!)
for example my text in database is:

```
a
b
c
.
.
.
```

Comment: Maybe `trim`? or a regex.. Is that text per line one one column? JS can't have multi line strings?

Comment: Thanks all 
The problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

To create a Javascript literal from a PHP variable, use `json_encode()`. It will translate the line breaks to escape sequences.

```
var js_variable = <?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>;
```